# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

i am trying to integrate my already working spring project with hibernate, but this is the error i am getting on start up.

```
EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/TelephoneDirectory] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:322)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.getSession(HibernateTemplate.java:457)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:393)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904)
    at com.emumba.telephonedirectory.repository.JdbcPersonDao.getPersonsList(JdbcPersonDao.java:36)
    at com.emumba.telephonedirectory.service.SimpleDirectoryManager.getAllPersons(SimpleDirectoryManager.java:23)
    at com.emumba.telephonedirectory.web.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have googled it but all i could find was that similar problems were caused by duplicates in classpath but i have looked very closely and i dont think their are any duplicates in my classpath. (may be i am wrong.) Heres a screen shot of jars in my classpath[image]

i am stuck, any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT: Search for org.hibernate.SessionFactory gives**

[image]

Comment: How many results do you get if you search for `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` using `ctrl-shift-t`?

Comment: Are you using maven - then try dependency:tree to get a tree structure of your dependencies . You could also search your ".classpath" file for duplicates .

Comment: @James i am editing the question to add the screen shot for the search for org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that you have `hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar` in your classpath, but Spring 3.1 uses `hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar` (see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.1.0.RELEASE) Spring 3.1 artifact and dependencies).

Remove Hibernate 4.0 and put Hibernate  3.6 instead in your classpath.

BTW, there might some more such miss matches. It's better to use maven to take care of dependencies.

**EDIT - some more details**

<strike>In Hibernate 3.6 the interface `Session` was in package `org.hibernate.classic` whereas in Hibernate 4.0 it was moved to the package `org.hibernate`.</strike>

In Hibernate 3.6 the `SessionFactory.openSession` no longer returns an `org.hibernate.classic.Session`, rather it returns an `org.hibernate.Session`. This is a refactor that breaks client code...

Comment: actually there are both interfaces `org.hibernate.classic.Session` and `org.hibernate.Session` in version 3 of hibernate

Comment: @bestsss - you're right. Both interfaces exists in 3.6. Only SessionFactory was changed to return `org.hibernate.Session` instead of `org.hibernate.classic.Session` - and that is what breaks client code. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without downgrading Hibernate?

Comment: @Dojo upgrade Spring... (and Hibernate while you're at it :-) )

Comment: "It's better to use maven to take care of dependencies." You still need to specify the versions, don't you?

Comment: Not as much as when not using Maven. With maven you specify versions only for your direct dependencies. Without Maven, you also have to specify the versions of the dependencies of your direct dependencies, and the dependencies of the dependencies of your direct dependencies and so on....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse as IDE and maven as a build tool, try to check build path entries. Sometimes, old JARs are added as classpath entries which are not overridden by maven clean or update.

You would need to remove those entries.

Refer below image

[image]

Above entries should not be present in build path, since they are not overridden by maven clean.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar kind of trouble; used a different version of apache-camel-extra helped resolving the problem

```
compile group: 'org.apache-extras.camel-extra', name: 'camel-hibernate', version: '2.18.0'
```

Our application setup

```
gradle
apache-camel
spring
hibernate
spring-jta and atomikos
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by transitive dependency of maven managed projects. Child will be using a particular version of an artefact but the parent would fetch a later version. In my case, I had to use

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the parent pom (i.e, I have specified the dependency version again in parent pom) to avoid this conflict.