# Full Hibernate Plugin only working with Hibernate3. Anyway with Hibernate4?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-s2hibernate

I been struggling with ***struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA*** for my CRUD demo project for learning purpose. Below is the error I get and than different hibernate dependencies tried to make it work. See below

**ERROR**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.createAndTestSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:284)
    com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:227)
    com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getNewSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:155)
```

*I understand from this thread answer* [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799121/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-opensessionlorg-hibe)

Than I started different maven dependeces to check hibernate version working with plugin and found

**NOT WORKING FROM BELOW VERSION**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**WORKING TILL THIS VERSION**

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Question:** Obviously don't want to use Hibernate3 so is there a way I can use latest hibernate4+ with struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA?

**Question:** What is the most widely used DI for hibernate in struts2. Should I go for ***Spring or google juice*** if above plugin not working?. Don't see any other viable solution for managing hibernate session except that ***viewpattern*** but say its antipattern and has many drawbacks.

Comment: As the answer you linked to indicates, Hibernate 4 has some API incompatibilities with Hibernate 3, so no, Hibernate 4 is not compatible with the version of the plugin you are trying to use.

Comment: @steven-benitez, Thanks. What should I do than?. Can you answer my last question?. Hope to get more feedback.

Comment: @steven-benitez, I think Open Session in View pattern is the most common way to be used?

Comment: Open Session in View is an excellent pattern. Also, I prefer Google Guice for DI, but to each his own.

Comment: @steven-benitez, Do you have any code sample on Google Guice with hibernate for DI?. I am looking for it. Can you share your own implementation. Thanks

Comment: My implementation is based on the Guice Persist extension, which is for JPA. Take a look at that and it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

use this config

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                            <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <componentProperties>
                        <outputfilename>schema.ddl</outputfilename>
                        <create>true</create>
                        <export>false</export>
                        <format>true</format>
                        <drop>true</drop>
                        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                        <propertyfile>target/test-classes/jdbc.properties</propertyfile>
                        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                    </componentProperties>
                </configuration>
                <!--<executions>-->
                <!--<execution>-->
                <!--<phase>process-test-resources</phase>-->
                <!--<goals>-->
                <!--<goal>hbm2ddl</goal>-->
                <!--</goals>-->
                <!--</execution>-->
                <!--</executions>-->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${jdbc.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${jdbc.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

and add `<hibernate.maven.plugin.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.maven.plugin.version>` to your pom properties.