# Hibernate4 openSession()

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing an application making use of the Hibernate framework (v4.3.4). When I run the tests, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at com.cartif.dwhconnector.manager.DatabaseCommunicator.createDBSession(DatabaseCommunicator.java:89)
    at com.cartif.dwhconnector.manager.DWHManager.createDBSession(DWHManager.java:53)
    at unittest.DWHConnectorTester.main(DWHConnectorTester.java:16)
```

The Java code is the next one:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure("com/cartif/hibernatemappings/hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

I have tried to use the Session class in the packages org.hibernate and org.hibernate.clasic, but the Exception is always the same. Could you help me, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799121/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-opensessionlorg-hibe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using different version of Hibernate during tests and different during appliaction compilation.