# Transaction Management using Hibernate with weblogic

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

Our application is deployed on weblogic

we use Hibernate and spring

The session factory is created through a user defined class which creates SessionFactories by reading the hibernate.cfg.xml file

So these are the steps :
Our custom class is defined in spring application context and we inject the format of theCFG  xml file in this class constructor :

```
<bean id="myCustomFactoryCreator"
    class="com.xyz.CustomFactoryCreator"
    singleton="true">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" >
            <property name="staticField">
                <value>com.xyz.MyConstants.HIBERNATE_CFG_XML</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In MyConstants.java:

```
public static final String HIBERNATE_CFG_XML = ".hibernate.cfg.xml";
```

So this way in the constructor - the code will iterate over all such files ending with ".hibernate.cfg.xml"
I will have different files for different clients :
"Client1.hibernate.cfg.xml" and "Client2.hibernate.cfg.xml" and so on ......

The code will iterate over all such files and create SessionFactories and then embed them into Springs HibernateTemplate and then store them in a map against the client name as key value pair : 
i.e. Client1 , HibernateTemplate1
Client2 , HibernateTemplate2 and so on 
I hope you get the picture

This bean "myCustomFactoryCreator" is then injected into my Dao:

```
<bean id="myCustomDao"
    class="com.xyz.MyCustomDao"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="criteriaConverter" ref="criteriaConverter" />
    <property name="myFactory" ref="myCustomFactoryCreator" />
</bean>
```

An example of my Hibernate.cfg.xml is as : ( I have multiple such files where schema name changes for each client )

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.datasource">MYDS</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="default_schema">CLIENT1SCHEMA</property>
</session-factory>
```

In my Dao - based on the client login - I get the appropriate HibernateTemplate and fire selects against the database 
Here we are using "DetachedCriteria" - sample code as follows :

```
List<T> inObjList=HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(DetachedCriteria, 0, 100);
```

So this is all fine and this works well 
This was when we were using Hibernate prior to 4.x

Thanks for your patience till now - will now get to the problem 
With Hibernate 4.x - I cannot any longer use Springs Hibernate Template 
Even if there is a way to use it - for reasons beyond my control I will not be allowed to use it - so I must go the SessionFactory route

So following the same logic as above - I stored in a map clientName and SessionFactory as against storing HibernateTemplate

The difference was that now I could no longer use - **HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria()** 
So what I did was got the SessionFactory from the map and then tried to get a session:

```
Session session=testSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

This failed with the error at above line with the exception :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

So did a bit of googling and looking at solutions in stackoverflow - I added the following line in my CFG files - I am not 100% sure if it is correct but used it assuming that mine being a managed environment where I am using weblogic managed datasource it would be JTA:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
```

This got me by the first exception - but then I hit the second exception :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

at the following line of code :

> Criteria subSelectCriteria =session.createCriteria(getType());

I come from the humble jdbc world - so I thought no big deal - I will simply add some transaction ala jdbc in the code - so I added this :

```
Transaction tx = null;
session.beginTransaction();
Criteria subSelectCriteria =session.createCriteria(getType());
tx.commit();
```

It failed at the above commit with the error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
at org.hibernate.engine.tx.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
at org.hibernate.engine.tx.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot call Connection.commit in distributed transaction.  
Transaction Manager will commit the resource manager when the distributed tx is committed.
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.commit(JTSConnection.java:663)
```

So then in my Hibernate CFG file I added the following line and removed the transaction management in my Java code in my Dao :

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
```

This gave the error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup specified
```

So please advise what I should do - and thanks for bearing with me on a long post

NOTE - I did find a solution where I can define each SessionFactory as a bean in spring and inject each of these into a

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager

However that would mean for each SessionFactory I would need to manually define a bean and inject the HibernateTransactinManager

Thank you !

Comment: I understand that the original issue is "I cannot any longer use Springs Hibernate Template Even if there is a way to use it - for reasons beyond my control I will not be allowed to use it - so I must go the SessionFactory route". Could you list down the error that appears in doing so?

Comment: @andy-dufresne - i tried to use HibernateTemplate - gave me the error - Exception in thread "Report Generator Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/hibernate/SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hi
bernate/classic/Session;
At the following line of code :
List inObjList=templ.findByCriteria

Comment: That seems to be a jar mismatch error and the solutions you have been trying don't seem related to this. Verify if the hibernate jar  are correct & compatible.

Comment: @andy-dufresne - we are using Hibernate 4.x - so am assuming my attempt to use HibernateTemplate is futile ? This link seems to indicate the problem to be related to Hibernate 4.x - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799121/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-opensessionlorg-hibe so I opened up my hiebrnate-core-4.3.4.Final.jar and it has no org.hibernate.classic.Session - this is present in 3.x version of hibernate while hibernate 4.x has org.hibernate.SessionFactory - thanks

Comment: If you are using hibernate 4 why are you using such a contraption? Hibernate has native support for multi tenancy (which is what you are trying to cobble together yourself). Saves you a lot of trouble (especially if the only thing that is different is the schema). Saves you a lot of configuration, custom classes and complex configuration. Everything can be done with a single `SessionFactory`.

Comment: thanks ! - will google and see if this works