# Spring JDBC throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.connection()Ljava/sql/Connection;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My problem is same as this one - [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799121/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-opensessionlorg-hibe)

I get the following exception while using Spring JDBCTemplate.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.connection()Ljava/sql/Connection;
```

The accepted answer in the link above, recommends downgrading Hibernate to a version supported by Spring.

This is not acceptable to me as I need the latest version of Hibernate to use its new features (and also benefit from bug fixes).

Is there a way to get it to work without downgrading hibernate?

Comment: so which versions of Spring and Hibernate do you currently have?

Comment: Spring is up to version 4.1.6; Hibernate's at 4.3.8.

Comment: @duffymo you could go further: why Java? What is it doing for you that C or assembler cannot?

Comment: Spring 3.0.5 and Hibernate is 4.3.8. I can upgrade Spring but there are several other projects that inter-operate and all of them are using Spring 3.0.5.  3.x to 4.x migration would break code in many places and necessitate code change. I don't have want to do that at this time...maybe later when we do a complete overhaul. Besides, why does Spring even have dependency on Hibernate? I was expecting Spring JDBC to be dependent only on JDBC.

Comment: You can't expect a really really old version of Spring to be automatically compatible with the lastest non-compatible changes in Hibernate. Regarding the second part of your comment: what is the complete stack trace of the exception? spring-jdbc doesn't have any dependency on Hibernate, and I doubt the error you get comes from spring-jdbc code.

Comment: @JBNizet - nope, that's a strawman.  Spring JDBC is a perfectly good alternative to Hibernate.  I'll bet that most people wouldn't be able to articulate why they chose Hibernate.  Lots do it for reasons that don't make sense.  I would say Hibernate and Spring JDBC template are orthogonal.  I shouldn't expect to see them in the same use case.

Answer (score 1):

I got this because I had upgraded from Hibernate4 to Hibernate 5 but still had a reference to 4 in the web.xml.

Was:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

changed to:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The transaction manager being used was JPA transaction manager. This was a left over from the early days when we were using JPA via Spring. We no longer do that, so I was not expecting Spring to break on Hibernate version update. On searching the bean definition, I found the incorrect reference to JPA/Hibernate and removed it. The application runs fine now.

Changed this:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">  
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
</bean>
```

To this:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```