# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, apache-camel

When trying to store the a bean using Hibernate, I am getting below Exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

at org.apacheextras.camel.component.hibernate.SpringTransactionStrategy$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionStrategy.java:43) ~[camel-hibernate-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
```

The hibernate Spring config is below.

```
<bean id="hibernate" class="org.apacheextras.camel.component.hibernate.HibernateComponent">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="transactionStrategy" ref="springTransactionStrategy"/>
</bean>
<bean id="springTransactionStrategy" class="org.apacheextras.camel.component.hibernate.SpringTransactionStrategy">
  <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="transactionTemplate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <value>
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
      hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
      show_sql=true
      format_sql=true
    </value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The Hibernate version is below.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
      </dependency>
```

I am using spring boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE and its derived dependencies

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
```

Any idea what is the solution? I found from one of the thread that upgrade hibernate and spring version but my hibernate and spring are already higher version. What about camel-hibernate? that comes from spring boot version. (Unfortunately I have to use 1.5.0.RELEASE due to co-mingled libraries)

Comment: I looked at below thread which suggested to upgrade versions. but I am already on higher versions (I Think) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799121/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-opensessionlorg-hibe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the hibernate version to 2.18.0 and I was able to resolve this error.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.0</version>
  </dependency>
```